# BizTalk message fails schema validation but processes just fine

Tags: biztalk

I have a BizTalk schema that looks something like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <SomeData></SomeData>
      <Detail>
         <MoreData1></MoreData1>
         <MoreData2></MoreData2>
         <MoreData3></MoreData3>
      </Detail>
   </Header>
</Root>
```

None of the elements have their Max Occurs or Min Occurs value set.

The message is created inside an orchestration by assigning an XmlDocument to it. The message is then used in several other places in the orchestration, and I have it being written to disk for examination.

The problem is that once the message is written out, if I try to use some of those same xml files as an input instance, they fail validation. For instance, some may have more than one `<Detail>` element, while some may be missing `<MoreData2>` .

Everything seems to be running, so I suppose it's not a huge concern at the moment, but I'm wondering how a message that fails schema validation won't throw an error when the application is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BizTalk, XML Messages are only validated in Pipelines.  Once the message has reached the orchestration, there is an assumption (for efficiency's sake) that the messages don't need to be validated against their schema.  When messages are created with transforms, the schema validation doesn't take place after.

So, in your case, the message coming in should have an XML Receive Pipeline with validation turned on.  This will stop the message from coming in.  Likewise, you can have validation turned on on the XML Send Pipeline.  This will stop bad messages form getting out.

There are options however to do schema validation in an orchestration.  First is described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dontian/archive/2006/07/28/86526.aspx).  There are also many more similar techniques if you Google/Bing it.

There is also an interesting article here where you can turn on XSD validation in Orchestration [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561963(v=bts.70).aspx).  This sounds good, but it is a server wide setting.  So it will apply to all applications... that includes the ones that are working.